# Three20: A good tutorial on TTStyle

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

What does each style means and how can they be used to create complex layouts?

Could anyone point to a good tutorial or any other starting point?

Comment: I am looking for TTStyles tutorial. I am very comfortable with Three20 otherwise but never got a chance to look at styles in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

http://www.mattvague.com/three20-stylesheets-tutorial

Also there's a tool called TTStyleBuilder that allows to interactively build TTStyles:

https://github.com/klazuka/TTStyleBuilder